# What does it mean that Flask doesn't support async tasks?

Tags: python, flask, asynchronous, fastapi

So I have come across several blog posts [like this](https://testdriven.io/blog/flask-async/) and StackOverflow comments talking about how Flask doesn't "actually" have async support. So I decided to create a script to test the hypothesis.

```
# I installed "Flask[async]"
import time
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import asyncio

app = Flask(__name__)

async def simulate_long_task():
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    print("Task completed!")
    return "Task completed!"

async def simulate_long_task2():
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("Task2 completed!")
    return "Task2 completed!"

@app.route('/test1')
async def test1():
    tasks = [simulate_long_task() for _ in range(2)]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    return jsonify({"message": results})

@app.route('/test2')
async def test2():
    s = time.time()
    tasks = [simulate_long_task2() for _ in range(2)]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    e =time.time()
    print(e-s)
    return jsonify({"message": results})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

my concurrent requests:

```
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/test1' & curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/test1' & curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/test1' &
curl 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/test2' & curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/test2' & curl --location 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/test2'
```

and this the logs:

```
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    50  100    50    0     0      9      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--    13{"message":["Task completed!","Task completed!"]}

100    50  100    50    0     0      9      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--    13{"message":["Task completed!","Task completed!"]}

100    50  100    50    0     0      9      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--    13{"message":["Task completed!","Task completed!"]}

100    52  100    52    0     0      5      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:--    13{"message":["Task2 completed!","Task2 completed!"]}

100    52  100    52    0     0      5      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:--    13{"message":["Task2 completed!","Task2 completed!"]}

100    52  100    52    0     0      5      0  0:00:10  0:00:10 --:--:--    13{"message":["Task2 completed!","Task2 completed!"]}
```

so what I expected to happen was that since several requests were made to each other test endpoints I thought all 6 server replies were going to come back at t=10 with each other (based on what folks were saying about flask not being async). To my surprise, Flask behaved exactly as an asynchronous app should. The three requests to "test1" returned at t=5 simultaneously, and the three requests to "test2" returned at t=10 together. This has left me puzzled about the criticisms of Flask not being suitable for asynchronous tasks. I'm curious to understand what potential issues I might be overlooking and in what scenarios Flask might not be the ideal choice, necessitating the use of FastAPI. My goal is to have my machine learning model send responses in one endpoint which several users might send requests to.

Comment: You might find this FastAPI-related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) helpful.

Comment: If it were true async they'd all run in the same thread. Instead, you have a separate thread running each request.

Comment: For a case where you're running a ML model -- if it's a _local_ model the overhead of running the LLM won't let you get to a high enough throughput for this to make any meaningful difference. (OTOH, a substantial subset of APIs for invoking LLMs have natively-async Python wrappers; if I were using, say, LMQL, then I would _definitely_ go the natively-async route -- accessing it synchronously has quite a bit of inefficiency since it's async under the hood itself).